# Load Data into input fields using Ajax/Json/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am working with jQuery, Ajax and PHP.
What I am trying to achieve is on-click (in php/html document) loading data into input fields.

My functions are the following

```
 functions.js


       //Laden Kopfdaten
$("#tablek tbody tr").on("click", function(){
  var ladeid = $(this).attr('id');
  LoadK(ladeid);
 });

 function LoadK(id) {
    var ladeid = ladeid;
    try {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }       
    catch (e) {
        try {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (failed) {
                req = null;
            }
        }
    }

    if (req == null) {
        alert("Error creating request object!");
    }
    req.open("GET", "laden.php?id="+id, true);

    // Nach Request auszuführende Aktion
    req.onreadystatechange = handleLoadK; 
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");       
    req.send(null);
}

function handleLoadK() {
    switch (req.readyState) {
        case 4:
        if (req.status != 200) {
            alert("Fehler:" + req.status);
        }
        else {
            // Formularfelder
            id = $("#dataid");
            herst_name = $("#herst");
            herst_strasse = $("#herst1");
            herst_hausnr = $("#herst2");
            herst_plz = $("#herst3");
            herst_stadt = $("#herst4");
            firma = $("#firma");
            liefernr = $("#firma1");
            firma_strasse = $("#firma2");
            firma_hausnr = $("#firma3");
            firma_plz = $("#firma4");
            firma_stadt = $("#firma5");
            auftragsnr = $("#info");
            auftragsdt = $("#info1");
            ordernr = $("#info2");
            sachbearbeiter = $("#info3");
            kundennr = $("#info4");
            verladedt = $("#info5");
            spedition = $("#info6");
            lieferdt = $("#info7");
            lieferuz = $("#info8");
            lieferungab = $("#info9");
            lieferscheinnr = $("#info10");
            relation = $("#info11");

            // Rückgabe des Servers
            var resultK = JSON.parse(req.responseText);

            // Ergebnisverarbeitung
            id.val(resultK.id);
            herst_name.val(resultK.herst_name);
            herst_strasse.val(resultK.herst_strasse);
            herst_hausnr.val(resultK.herst_hausnr);
            herst_plz.val(resultK.herst_plz);
            herst_stadt.val(resultK.herst_stadt);
            firma.val(resultK.firma);
            liefernr.val(resultK.liefernr);
            firma_strasse.val(resultK.firma_strasse);
            firma_hausnr.val(resultK.firma_hausnr);
            firma_plz.val(resultK.firma_plz);
            firma_stadt.val(resultK.firma_stadt);
            auftragsnr.val(resultK.auftragsnr);
            auftragsdt.val(resultK.auftragsdt);
            ordernr.val(resultK.ordernr);
            sachbearbeiter.val(resultK.sachbearbeiter);
            kundennr.val(resultK.kundennr)
            verladedt.val(resultK.verladedt);
            spedition.val(resultK.spedition);
            lieferdt.val(resultK.lieferdt);
            lieferuz.val(resultK.lieferuz);
            lieferungab.val(resultK.lieferungab);
            lieferscheinnr.val(resultK.lieferscheinnr);
            relation.val(resultK.relation);
        }
    }
}
```

my load.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        include('./inc/kopf.class.php');
        $kopf0->load($_GET['id']);
        $result = $kopf0->kopfdaten;
        $json=json_encode($result);
        print_r ($json);
    }

    else {
        include('./inc/position.class.php');
        $pos0->load($_GET['positionsid']);
        $result = $pos0->positionsdaten; 
        print(trim(json_encode($result)));
    }
?>
```

Since I have 2 different documents I am implementing a load for there's if-else in this one. For now it doesn't matter though, I am working on the "if"-part.

part from the table used (its implementied via ajax in a div id="tablek")

```
<?php   
        for($i=0;$i < $anzahl;$i++){
        ?>      
        <tr id=" <?php echo $kdaten[$i][0]; ?> ">
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                <?php 
                    echo $kdaten[$i][0];
                ?>
            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                <?php
                    echo $kdaten[$i][1];
                ?>
            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                <?php
                echo $kdaten[$i][2];
                ?>
            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                <?php
                    echo $kdaten[$i][3];
                ?>
            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                <?php
                    echo $kdaten[$i][4];
                ?>
            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                <?php
                    echo $kdaten[$i][5];
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Here's my main problem.
my  has an ID, the one from it's row, but if I click on any of the rows nothing is loading into the input fields. I get no error, no reactions, whatsoever. Guy across my desk works on something equal and we have about the same code. For him it works, which really confuses me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT: source code snippet from generated table.php

```
<table cellspacing="0px" width=70%>
        <tr>
            <th class="t4">
                ID
            </th>
            <th class="t4">
                Hersteller
            </th>
            <th class="t4">
                Stadt
            </th>
            <th class="t4">
                Firma
            </th>
            <th class="t4">
                Stadt
            </th>
            <th class="t4">
                Kundennummer
            </th>
            <th class="t4">
                Löschen
            </th>
            <th class="t4">
                Positionen
            </th>
            <th class="t4">
                Druckvorschau
            </th>
            <th class="t4">
                Anzahl Positionen
            </th>
        </tr>


        <tr id=" 1 ">
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                1           </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                Vallah          </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                00000000000         </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                <form action="einfuegen.php?aktion=loeschen" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="1" >
                <input type="button" value="Löschen" name="1" onClick="deleteK(this.name)" style="background-color:Lavender">
                </form>
            <td class="t1 t4">
                <form action="positionen.php?aktion=anzeigen&id=1" method="post">
                <input type="submit" id="showpos" value="Positionen" style="background-color:Lavender">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4">
                <a href="freixenet.php?id=1" style="background-color:lightblue">Rechnungsdruck</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id=" 2 ">
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                2           </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                BBBBAA          </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                djaksdkjas          </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                djaskdjksajdas          </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                hwadjwadhjwa            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                00002190321         </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                <form action="einfuegen.php?aktion=loeschen" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="2" >
                <input type="button" value="Löschen" name="2" onClick="deleteK(this.name)" style="background-color:Lavender">
                </form>
            <td class="t1 t4">
                <form action="positionen.php?aktion=anzeigen&id=2" method="post">
                <input type="submit" id="showpos" value="Positionen" style="background-color:Lavender">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4">
                <a href="freixenet.php?id=2" style="background-color:lightblue">Rechnungsdruck</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id=" 3 ">
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                3           </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                xxxxxx          </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                dwdadwa         </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                dwadwadwa           </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                dwadwadwa           </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                00000121321         </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                <form action="einfuegen.php?aktion=loeschen" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="3" >
                <input type="button" value="Löschen" name="3" onClick="deleteK(this.name)" style="background-color:Lavender">
                </form>
            <td class="t1 t4">
                <form action="positionen.php?aktion=anzeigen&id=3" method="post">
                <input type="submit" id="showpos" value="Positionen" style="background-color:Lavender">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4">
                <a href="freixenet.php?id=3" style="background-color:lightblue">Rechnungsdruck</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id=" 5 ">
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                5           </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                jkejkwqk            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                jllkjew         </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                jqwekwq         </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                jkewqk          </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                00000325322         </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                <form action="einfuegen.php?aktion=loeschen" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="5" >
                <input type="button" value="Löschen" name="5" onClick="deleteK(this.name)" style="background-color:Lavender">
                </form>
            <td class="t1 t4">
                <form action="positionen.php?aktion=anzeigen&id=5" method="post">
                <input type="submit" id="showpos" value="Positionen" style="background-color:Lavender">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4">
                <a href="freixenet.php?id=5" style="background-color:lightblue">Rechnungsdruck</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id=" 6 ">
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                6           </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                HERRU           </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                Herrouuoou          </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                Herruuuu            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                Herruouo            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                03216675454         </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                <form action="einfuegen.php?aktion=loeschen" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="6" >
                <input type="button" value="Löschen" name="6" onClick="deleteK(this.name)" style="background-color:Lavender">
                </form>
            <td class="t1 t4">
                <form action="positionen.php?aktion=anzeigen&id=6" method="post">
                <input type="submit" id="showpos" value="Positionen" style="background-color:Lavender">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4">
                <a href="freixenet.php?id=6" style="background-color:lightblue">Rechnungsdruck</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id=" 10 ">
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                10          </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                jujujuju            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                lololo          </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                ololoollo           </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                popopo          </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                00008978076         </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                <form action="einfuegen.php?aktion=loeschen" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="10" >
                <input type="button" value="Löschen" name="10" onClick="deleteK(this.name)" style="background-color:Lavender">
                </form>
            <td class="t1 t4">
                <form action="positionen.php?aktion=anzeigen&id=10" method="post">
                <input type="submit" id="showpos" value="Positionen" style="background-color:Lavender">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4">
                <a href="freixenet.php?id=10" style="background-color:lightblue">Rechnungsdruck</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id=" 11 ">
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                11          </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                hehu            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                hetze           </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                hueh            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                xoxo            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                00032553335         </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                <form action="einfuegen.php?aktion=loeschen" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="11" >
                <input type="button" value="Löschen" name="11" onClick="deleteK(this.name)" style="background-color:Lavender">
                </form>
            <td class="t1 t4">
                <form action="positionen.php?aktion=anzeigen&id=11" method="post">
                <input type="submit" id="showpos" value="Positionen" style="background-color:Lavender">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4">
                <a href="freixenet.php?id=11" style="background-color:lightblue">Rechnungsdruck</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id=" 12 ">
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                12          </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                hehu            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                hetze           </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                hueh            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                xoxo            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="180px">
                00032553335         </td>
            <td class="t1 t4" width="15px">
                <form action="einfuegen.php?aktion=loeschen" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="12" >
                <input type="button" value="Löschen" name="12" onClick="deleteK(this.name)" style="background-color:Lavender">
                </form>
            <td class="t1 t4">
                <form action="positionen.php?aktion=anzeigen&id=12" method="post">
                <input type="submit" id="showpos" value="Positionen" style="background-color:Lavender">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td class="t1 t4">
                <a href="freixenet.php?id=12" style="background-color:lightblue">Rechnungsdruck</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

EDIT: my main document (with implemented table and updated id's)

```
<?php
    // Klasseneinbindung
    include('inc/kopf.class.php'); 

    // Spalten
    for ($i=0;$i <= 24; $i++){
        $result[$i]="";
    }

    // Köpfe zählen 
    $kopfcount = $kopf0->zaehlen();

    // Daten suchen
    if(isset($_POST['suchbegriff'])){
        $kopf0->suchen($_POST['suchbegriff']);
        $kdaten = $kopf0->tabledata;
        $anzahl = $kopf0->anzahl;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheeteinfg.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/einfuegen.js"></script>
        <title> Datensatzbearbeitung </title>
        <h2>
            Kopfsätze
        </h2>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:aquamarine">
        <form action="einfuegen.php?aktion=speichern" id="kopfform" method="post">
        <legend>
            <p id="uhr"></p>
            <p id="result"></p>
        </legend>
        <br/>

        <!--Validierungserror-->
        <p id="error_para" ></p>
            <table width="83%">
                <tr>
                    <td valign=top>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend> Herstellerinformationen </legend>
                                <label>Hersteller*<br/><input type="text" id="herst" name="hersteller" value="<?php echo $result[1]?>"/>
                                        <!-- <input type="text" value="" id="checkresponse" style="background-color:aquamarine; border:none" readonly> -->
                                </label><br/>
                                <label>
                                    Strasse* <br/><input type="text" id="herst1" name="herststrasse" value="<?php echo $result[2]?>">
                                </label><br/>
                                <label>
                                    Hausnummer* <br/><input type="text" id="herst2" name="hausnummerherst" value="<?php echo $result[3]?>">
                                </label><br/>
                                <label>
                                    PLZ* <br/><input type="number" id="herst3" name="plzherst" onchange="if (!this.value.match(/^[0-9]{5}$/))  {this.style.background='#f00'; alert('Die Postleitzahl ist ungültig, bitte anpassen'); if(showAlert==true){showAlert=false};}
                                        else {this.style.background='#00ff00';}" value="<?php echo $result[4]?>">
                                </label><br/>
                                <label>
                                    Stadt* <br/><input type="text" id="herst4" name="stadtherst" value="<?php echo $result[5]?>">
                                </label>        
                        </fieldset>
                    </td>
                    <td valign=top>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend> Empfängerinformationen </legend>
                            <label>
                                Lieferungsempfänger*<br/> <input type="text" id="firma" name="empfaenger" value="<?php echo $result[6]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                            <label>
                                Liefernummer* <br/><input type="number" id="firma1" name="liefernr" value="<?php echo $result[7]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                            <label>
                                Lieferstrasse* <br/><input type="text" id="firma2" name="lieferstr" value="<?php echo $result[8]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                            <label>
                                Hausnummer* <br/><input type="text" id="firma3" name="lieferhausnr" value="<?php echo $result[9]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                            <label>
                                PLZ* <br/><input type="number" id="firma4" name="lieferplz" onchange="if (!this.value.match(/^[0-9]{5}$/)) 
                                                                                                {this.style.background='#f00'; alert('Die Postleitzahl ist ungültig, bitte anpassen'); if(showAlert==true){showAlert=false};}
                                                                                                else {this.style.background='#00ff00';}"
                                                                                                value="<?php echo $result[10]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                            <label>
                                Stadt* <br/><input type="text" id="firma5" name="lieferstadt" value="<?php echo $result[11]?>">
                            </label>
                        </fieldset>
                    </td>
                    <td width="35%">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend> Lieferdetails </legend>
                            <label> 
                                Auftragsnummer* <br/><input type="number" id="info" name="auftragsnr" value="<?php echo $result[12]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                            <label>
                                Auftragsdt <br/> <input type="date" name="auftragsdt" id="info1" value="<?php echo $result[13]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                            <label>
                                Ordernummer* <br/><input type="number" name="ordernr" id="info2" value="<?php echo $result[14]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                            <label>
                                Sachbearbeiter <br/><input type="text" name="sachbearbeiter" id="info3" value="<?php echo $result[15]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                            <label>
                                Kundennummer* <br/><input type="number" name="kundennr" id="info4" value="<?php echo $result[16]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                            <label>
                                Verladedatum <br/><input type="date" name="verladedt" id="info5" value="<?php echo $result[17]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                            <label>
                                Spedition <br/><input type="text" name="spedi" id="info6" value="<?php echo $result[18]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                            <label>
                                Lieferdatum <br/><input type="date" name="lieferdt" id="info7" value="<?php echo $result[19]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                            <label>
                                Lieferuhrzeit <br/><input type="time" name="lieferuz" id="info8" value="<?php echo $result[20]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                            <label>
                                Lieferung ab <br/><input type="datetime-local" name="liefab" id="info9" value="<?php echo $result[21]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                            <label>
                                Lieferscheinnummer* <br/><input type="number" name="lieferscheinnr" id="info10" value="<?php echo $result[22]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                            <label>
                                Relation <br/><input type="text" name="relation" id="info11" value="<?php echo $result[23]?>">
                            </label><br/>
                        </fieldset>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>
                                Aktionen
                            </legend>
                                <input type="Button" id="kopfspeichern" value="Daten speichern" style="background-color:Lavender"/>
                                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $result[0]?>" id="dataid">
                                </form>
                                <br/>
                                <input type="reset" value="Änderungen zurücksetzen" style="background-color:Lavender" onClick="return confirm('Eingaben verwerfen?')">                  
                                <input type="button" onclick="Kopieren()" id="Copypaste" value="Kopieren (Laden - Kopieren - Speichern)" <?php if (empty($_POST['id'])){ ?>disabled="disabled"<?php } ?>>
                                <form action="einfuegen.php" method="post">
                                <input type="Button" onClick="NeuK()" value="Neuer Eintrag" style="background-color:Lavender">
                            </form>
                        </td>
                        <form action="einfuegen.php?search" method="post">
                            <input type="Submit" value="Suchen" style="background-color:Lavender"> <input type="text" name="suchbegriff" id="suchbegriff" placeholder="Suchbegriff eingeben" style="background-color:white">
                            <br/>
                        </form>
                        <form action="einfuegen.php" method="post">
                            <input type="submit" value="Vollansicht" style="background-color:Lavender">
                        </form>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <legend readonly>
                            Datensatz-ID:   
                                <input type="text" name="id" id="dataid" value="<?php   echo $result[0];?>">
                        </legend>
                    </fieldset>
                </tr>
            </table>
            Zuletzt aktualisiert: <div id="date"> </div>
            <br/>
            <legend>
                Anzahl der Einträge:
            <?php   
                echo $kopfcount;
            ?> 
            <br/><br/>
            </legend>
            <br/>
            <b> Datensatzliste </b>
            <div id="tablek"></div>
            <script> 
                function Kopieren(){
                    document.getElementById('id5').value = "";
                    alert('Die Daten wurden kopiert');
                }
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the resulting html code of your table from "view page source" after the page is generated?

Comment: what type of element is `$("#0")` etc? Normally with a jQuery object you'd use `.val()` to set its value, rather than `.value`. That's assuming it's an input field. If its some other kind of element you probably want to set the contents  of the element using `.html()` or `.text()`.

Comment: edited my post, full code wouldve been too much code, I guess you get the idea from it. since it's a loop it's repetetive until the end

Comment: You have spaces in your ids, are you sure it's not causing troubles? Try to remove spaces in `id=" <?php echo $kdaten[$i][0]; ?> "`

Comment: mostly text/number-input-fields, some of them are dates

Comment: I've removed the spaces just now, no change

Comment: hm.  From your edit: you have got `<tr id="1"`. And `herst_strasse = $("#1");`. So...with `herst_strasse.value = resultK.herst_strasse`, you try to set the "value" of a whole table row. This does not make much sense. But anyway instead of all this long-winded individual allocation of variables to fields, you might find it neater and quicker to use a templating engine (e.g. Mustache or one of those)

Comment: should I try changing the #1, #2 and so on to different id-names? do you think it's causing the complication? for now I kind of want to do it without further plugins/frameworks etc. 

after I would go for a easier solution.

Comment: I've checked back with my co-worker and he appears to have set "#1" and so on aswell while using the same code for on-click loading.
Found a mistake and changed my JSON resultK processing code to:              id.val(resultK.id) and so on, didn't do the trick yet

Comment: just to try it I've changed all id's to regular names, looks better but didn't fix my problem. does anyone see other possible problems? the "click" function doesn't seem to trigger

Comment: Here's a little example on returning row id with jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/m062m7sn/ . Also, I don't see a table id (which should be #tablek according to your code) in your resulting table html.

Comment: the table.html is bound into another .php document via div id = tablek, i'm displaying it via a function                       
                                                                     
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#tablek").load("tabelle.php");
var url = window.location.href;
var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
$("#tablep").load("tabellepos.php?id="+id);
});

Comment: can you update the question with your latest code and HTML? It would help to clarify

Comment: I've edited the parts I have changed and also added my main document for further clarification, showing my situation as a whole. though it's loads of code. thanks for being so helpful in general.

Comment: Have you tried adding console.log into your click function to know for sure if it's working or not? Just try to console.log($(this).attr('id')) and see if it's working.

Comment: Tried it, nothing shows up. So there probably is an issue within my function? Have you found any mistakes that don't give an error? Because I am just getting 0

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see the full picture. If you're saying that your function doesn't fire then it means either that your selector is wrong ("#tablek tbody tr") or your div, which is #tablek from what I understood, is being populated after you set your event listener (on click). Mb you should try `console.log($("#tablek tbody tr").html())` right before `$("#tablek tbody tr").on("click", function(){` and see if it's empty.

Comment: without .html() : [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
with .html() : undefined

So he doesn't know #tablek tbody tr?

Comment: I have checked Elements via Browser. It shows I have this structure 

div -> table -> tbody -> tr
I tried adding table to my function but I still get undefined.
Also I've checked and my table and tablek are indifferent in size.

table size = 853 x 2892
tablek size = 841 x 2892

Comment: I've added $document).ready(function() { before
$("#tablek ......").on.....

Undefined in console disappeard yet not showing me anything and not reacting at all.

Comment: Maybe you should try to put your `$("#tablek tbody tr").on("click", function(){}` in the complete function of jquery's .load() ? Like this: `$("#tablek").load("tabelle.php", function() {
  $("#tablek tbody tr").on("click", function(){
    console.log('Does it work this way?')
    var ladeid = $(this).attr('id');
    LoadK(ladeid);
  });
});`

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by user stee1rat

> Maybe you should try to put your $("#tablek tbody tr").on("click", function(){} in the complete function of jquery's .load() ? Like this: $("#tablek").load("tabelle.php", function() { $("#tablek tbody tr").on("click", function(){ console.log('Does it work this way?') var ladeid = $(this).attr('id'); LoadK(ladeid); }); });

Since I had my 'showtable' function and my loading function seperate it didn't work but merging both of them worked perfectly fine, no errors whatsoever.

Formatted code:

```
$("#tablek").load("tabelle.php", function() { 
  $("#tablek tbody tr").on("click", function(){ 
    console.log('Does it work this way?') 
    var ladeid = $(this).attr('id'); 
    LoadK(ladeid); 
  }); 
});
```